# Selenium ChromeDriver C# only works in headless mode

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Project Properties:

- C# .NET Framework 4.7.2
- Repository: https://github.com/theomnislayer/ChromeDriverError
- Visual Studio 2019 Pro. The Repo above should work with VS Code

Nuget Packages installed:

- Selenium.WebDriver 3.141.0
- Selenium.Support 3.141.0
- Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver 94.0.4606.6100
- Xunit 2.4.1
- Xunit.Runner.VisualStudio 2.4.3

Error Description:

1. Starting from Chrome 93.x and ChromeDriver 93.x or newer
2. Without the --headless argument in chromeoptions, the following error is encountered:

   ```
   Message: 
   OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
     (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
     (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
   ```
3. Expected behavior: Chrome should NOT crash even without the headless argument

Replicating the error:

1. Sample Code:

   ```
    public void DisabledHeadless()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
        options.AddArgument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
        options.AddArguments("no-sandbox");
        options.AddArgument("enable-automation");
        options.AddArgument("test-type=browser");
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing", "enabled");
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
        //options.AddArgument("--headless");

        var driver = new ChromeDriver(
            Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
            options,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
    }
   ```
2. Run the test, Error is encountered.

Workaround:

1. Sample Code:

   ```
    public void EnabledHeadless()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
        options.AddArgument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
        options.AddArguments("no-sandbox");
        options.AddArgument("enable-automation");
        options.AddArgument("test-type=browser");
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing", "enabled");
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");

        //Weird = Starting from V.93, without this argument, CHROME CRASHES!
        options.AddArgument("--headless");

        var driver = new ChromeDriver(
            Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
            options,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
    }
   ```

Is there a fix for this without headless enabled? Errors were not encountered with Chrome 92 or prior. Thanks in advance!